# Register simple custom Control (not UserControl)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls

I'm trying to implement a simple derived Control as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306288/custom-asp-net-container-control/306310#306310)  but can't seem to register it for use.
UserControl's work fine with

```
<pages>
     <controls>
          <add tagPrefix="prefix1" src="~/Folder1/UserControl1.ascx" tagName="tag1"/>
```

But simple classes that derive from System.Web.UI.Control - do not.

I've tried various variations of the following

```
<pages>
     <controls>
          <add tagPrefix="prefix1" src="~/Folder1/Control1.cs" tagName="tag1"  assembly="assembly1" namespace=" assembly1.Control1" />
```

But with no success.

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/306408/578411) for how to register controls

Comment: I can add UserControls simply. They're in the project, and don't need to be compiled separately. Can't I do the same for Controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for src attribute. Update your question with the namespace and class name of the control and I'll correct my answer

```
<add tagPrefix="prefix1" assembly="assembly1" namespace="assembly1.Control1" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just two remarks: a) I had to delete the **obj** and **bin** folders first, and b) it turns out that `assembly1.` is not needed in the `namespace`.